# Как сделать дату сборки всегда актуальной?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, define, macro

Мне в приложении нужно знать дату его сборки. Я пытаюсь использовать макрос `__DATE__`, но есть подозрение, что если я не будут менять файл, в котором этот макрос находится, то этот файл не будет перекомпилироваться и значение этого макроса останется старым.
Как гарантировать, чтобы этот макрос обновлялся при каждой сборке?
Может быть есть какой-то другой, более надёжный способ узнать дату сборки модуля или приложения?

Comment: Пересоберите проект заново. Также имеет смысл отказаться от системы сборки, собирающей файлы только после изменений.

Comment: Для гарантированной перекомпиляции можно настроить pre-build event или отключить инкрементальную сборку для релиза

Comment: Используйте свой макрос в stdafx.h, для этого нужно использовать опцию precompilled headers. Возможно использование макроса в этом файле увеличит время компиляции, потому что он будет постоянно меняться  и предкомпиляция не будет приносить преимуществ во времени. Однако это может решить вашу проблему.

Comment: В Visual Studio 2017 как знаю, есть кнопка Сборка->Пересобрать решение, можно использовать её (Ctrl + Alt + F7),

Answer (score 0):

Такого рода проблему можно решить добавив скрипт, который будет запускаться перед сборкой. Этот скрипт может либо "касаться" какого-то определенного файла чтобы поменять дату последнего изменения (и таким образом спровоцировать его пересборку), либо он может и вовсе генерировать свой собственный макрос с датой сборки, который вы потом включите в свой код.

Вы можете узнать о пользовательских этапах сборки в MSBuild [из этой стати](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/specifying-build-events?view=vs-2019) на MSDN.

Если вы используете в своем проекте CMake, вы также можете выполнить произвольную команду во время геренации проекта, и воспользоваться ее выводом. Таким образом, к примеру, мы в наших проектах создаем макрос с хэшем коммита в git.